# mvn unit test common resource folder and read file functionality

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea

I have the following directory structure for tests

```
test
 /java
   /com.mycompany
     test1Test
     test2Test
 /resources
  /jsonFiles
    file1.json
    file2.json
```

Then in each of my tests I read from a corresponding input json file:

```
@Test
public void testFile1()
{
   // read a file from the resources directory
   myobj = new myObject();
   myobj.setFileContentsAsString(test1Test.class.getResourcesAsStream("/jsonFiles/file1.json");
}
```

My question is two part:

1) What is a better way to read in the file contents w/o having to specify the className.getResourceAsStream() being since it will be used in multiple test cases for each test class.  Seems I reuse something better?

2) Where can I put the path to look for the file resources instead of having to hard code "jsonFiles" as a prefix to the actual file?i would rather call something as absolute as ("file1.json");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really specific to mvn. You could create a method in a super class or test utility class :

```
public static InputStream getJsonFileAsStream(String jsonFile)
{
    return ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/jsonFiles/" + jsonFile);
}
```

You could then reuse it where you need to.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to read the files is using the resourceAsStream. But here is something which you can do to avoid writing the multiple read of the same file  operation in different test cases.

1. Write a Base test class which has

   ```
   public class BaseTest{

    protected myObject myobj;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       // read a file from the resources directory
       myobj = new myObject();
       myobj.setFileContentsAsString(
                  test1Test.class.getResourcesAsStream("/jsonFiles/file1.json");
    } }
   ```

and all the classes which needs to resuse this method should be called like

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }
}
```

So now the object **myobj** is available in all the test classes where you load only once.

the second question is based on the requirement.

[EDIT]

```
 public class BaseTest{

     private String filePath;
     public BaseTest(String filePath) {
         this.filePath = filePath;
     }
     protected myObject myobj;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
        // read a file from the resources directory
        myobj = new myObject();
        myobj.setFileContentsAsString(
                   test1Test.class.getResourcesAsStream("/jsonFiles/" + filePath);
     } }
```

So the base class will force its extending classes to create a public constructor which should pass the file name also.

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {

    public Test1() {
        super("file1.json");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }
}

public class Test2 extends BaseTest {

    public Test2() {
        super("file2.json");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }
}
```

In this way, each test file can pass a different file name.

Hope this helps

Comment: thx, how can I reuse for multiple files and test classes?  file1.json for test1Test, file2.json for test2Test?  What you have looks like it only supports only one instance or many BaseTest classes?